# Latest JFrog Artifactory Download "Path must be a string" error

Tags: artifactory

I created a release in VSTS and deploy, but I got the "Path must be a string" error. Does anyone has tried using the latest release of Artifactory ?

Comment: Can you specify which task do you run and provide logs information?

Answer (score 1):

The latest JFrog-Artifactory-VSTS-Extension v1.0.4 include a fix for that issue.
It uses 'System.DefaultWorkingDirectory' instead of 'Agent.BuildDirectory'.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I found out that the task doesn't work in release pipelines, only in build pipelines, since it's looking for the Agent.BuildDirectory variable.